# JQuery: multiple width functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, triggers, resize

I was not able to put together a snippet but basically this is what I'm stuck with, down here I have made a function which checks if the user has scrolled 70px, this is for the navbar to when the user has scrolled 70px the navbar becomes fixed and moves with the user. Now I have made multiple .width functions to check if the device is a mobile device, if so the margin-left of the .center class should be 0, but if I use a .resize function in the >= 70 if statement and the <70 if statement, it doesn't work. If I remove the .width function in one of the if-statements it works again, it's a true pain and I can't let it seem to work.

```
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".navbar-default");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var $window = $(window);

            if (scroll >= 70) {

                header.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                $(".navbar-brand").css('display','block');

                $window.resize(function resize() {
                    if ($window.width() < 767) {
                        return $(".center").css('margin-left','0px');
                    }

                $(".center").css('margin-left','30px');

                }).trigger('resize');

            } else if(scroll < 70) {

                header.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");

                $window.resize(function resize() {
                    if ($window.width() < 767) {
                        return $(".navbar-brand").css('display','block');
                    }

                $(".navbar-brand").css('display','none');
                $(".center").css('margin-left','150px');

                }).trigger('resize');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: why using this `$window.resize(function resize() {`

Comment: Seemed like the most simple method for me, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: but this will only work when widow resize

Comment: Do you know a way how I can check the window width whilst checking the scroll distance? Cause that's basically what I'm stuck with

Comment: simply remove this funciton and only put the content inside. You can check my answer to see if i understand your needs